# Debian - auth.log missing from /var/log

Tags: logs

I am learning Debian on RaspberryPI. 
I've installed 'logwatch' and 'fail2ban' recently and those two were working Great!

A few days ago I've spotted that I don't have a file "auth.log" but I do have "auth.log.gz1" etc. (so archive data)

I've used command:

```
touch auth.log
```

to create this file, than `chown root:adm`
to change its premissions.

However this file is still not working - I can't see any entry in to for the last 2 days even if I was loging in trough SSH.

Can you advise:

1. why this file is gone? where to look for a reasons?
2. how to fix the issue, so all my SSH connections (and attacks) will be recorded?

PS.

```
pi@pi ~ $ uname -a
```

Linux pi.local 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you using Debian or Raspbian ?

Comment: This answer may help at some point too; https://superuser.com/a/809048

Answer (score 14):

I got bitten by this when I tried to configure `fail2ban` on a "minimal" Ubuntu 20.04 LTS image. On Ubuntu `fail2ban` looks for authentication events in `/var/log/auth.log`. However, in the "minimal" image only the `systemd` "journal" facility is available, the file `auth.log` is missing and then `fail2ban` won't start. To get the good old log files back, I installed `rsyslog`:

`sudo apt-get install rsyslog`

and then `fail2ban` started working properly.

Credit where credit is due: the idea for this solution came from @Bloodden 's answer which seems to be somewhat unfairly voted down...

Answer (score 13):

From Debian 8 (Jessie), `systemd` is installed by default. There is, by default, no more `/var/log/auth.log`. You can view the log of sshd with the following command :

```
journalctl -u ssh.service
```

Comment: Put a -f on the end for a tail -f  experience.

Comment: This is not precise, the relevant change is from Debian 12 (bookworm).
"From bookworm, rsyslog is no longer installed by default" (https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#changes-to-system-logging)

Comment: @gentooise I'm not convinced by your statement. Debian 12 was released in 2023, but the question is from 2014 and the answer from 2017.

Comment: I'm on Fedora 39, and the correct command seems to be `journalctl -u sshd.service` now.

Answer (score 5):

Creating the file manually won't do anything: if the logging system wants to use the file, it will create it.

Perhaps as part of the package installation or perhaps as part of some other configuration, you've somehow changed the configuration of your logging system. By default, Debian uses [sysklogd](http://freecode.com/projects/sysklogd), configured via `/etc/syslog.conf`, and `auth.log` comes from a line

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
```

Maybe you modified `/etc/syslog.conf`, or maybe you switched to [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) (which is a lot more powerful than sysklogd, but also bigger and more complex.

Comment: There is no more `/etc/syslog.conf` in Debian 8 (Jessie).

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni `/etc/syslog.conf` still exists, but as before, it's only used by sysklogd. Sysklogd is no longer the default on jessie since it defaults to systemd and systemd replaces a lot of system functionality by its own, including logging.

Answer (score 3):

Install `syslog-ng`:

```
apt-get install syslog-ng
```

Comment: I gave a +1 here because this answer led me to the solution (see my answer for details). Don't really understand the downvotes this answer received BTW.

Comment: Possibly because it doesn't explain why this is a good solution